# How can I implement Core Bluetooth Functionality for multiple devices?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Okay, I have been successful so far in my core bluetooth journeys. I just need to clarify a few things regarding what the best practises are for using bluetooth in my app. My queries are:

First of all, I want to know how best I can optimize my code. Do i have to discover and connect for every page that I want to use bluetooth on? How is it possible for me to connect to a peripheral and use that connection on the next page in the app without having to call the `didConnectPeripheral:` function everywhere?

Secondly, I have been meaning to connect two peripheral devices onto my app. I know that this is possible, but how does it work? Is the connection timeshared or are they happening simultaneously? Do I have to disconnect one to be able to access the other? What is the optimal approach to connect two devices to the app without each other's connection interfering with each other?

Any directions would be much appreciated! Cheers

Comment: Use a singleton to manage your BLE connection, allowing to keep the connection in all your "pages". You can connect to various BLE devices at the same time (limit is 8 I think). Just keep references for them.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't need to connect to device for each 'screen' you have. Create one `CBCentralManager`, connect to given device once and connection will exist(unless you explicitly tell it to disconnect) for the whole lifecycle of this `CBCentralManager`.
2. You can connect to several `CBPeripheral` devices simultaneously by using single `CBCentralManager` but `CBPeripheral` cannot connect to anyone, it just accepts connections from `CBCentral`'s.

Recently I've released my own wrapper around CoreBluetooth technology called [YRBluetooth](https://github.com/solomidSF/YRBluetooth). It simplifies a lot of CoreBluetooth things by providing another abstraction level. There you can find simple demo chat application that was built using YRBluetooth.